# Sumador con tkinter

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter

Hola es mi primera pregunta en esta pagina, espero no cometer errores en la formulacion de la misma,bueno lo que pasa es que quiero hacer una app que cuando de click a un boton, aumente el valor de una variable y aparezca en el cuadro de texto de la ventana.

El problema es que no se como tomar una variable entera, digamos n, que cuando pulse el boton sume +1 al valor de la variable n y que quede guardado en la variable n.

espero que haya quedado clara la pregunta. les dejo mi codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
n=0
def sumar():
    global n
    n+=1
    e=str(n)
    produccion.set(e)     


raiz=Tk()
produccion=StringVar()
prod=Entry(raiz,textvariable=produccion)
prod.pack(side=TOP)
contador=ttk.Button(raiz,text="sumador",command=sumar())
contador.pack(side=BOTTOM)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un error bastante común, a `command` **se le pasa una referencia a la función/método a ejecutar** cuando el botón sea pulsado, tu estas pasándole el retorno de la misma ya que haces `command=sumar()`. Con `sumar()` estas llamando a la función por lo que al argumento `command` le pasas `None` (que es lo que retorna `sumar`). Debería ser `command=sumar`, observa la falta de los paréntesis.

Puedes prescindir de la variable global `n` si lo deseas a costa de un casting a `int`. Por otro lado, `from modulo import *` es generalmente considerada una mala práctica en Python, dificulta la legibilidad del código, puedes solapar nombres de un import con otro sin darte cuenta (con los consiguientes errores) y se pobla innecesariamente el namespace actual. Como dice el zen de Python:

> "Explícito es mejor que implícito".

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def sumar():
    produccion.set(str(int(produccion.get()) + 1))     


raiz = tk.Tk()
produccion = tk.StringVar(raiz, "0")
prod = tk.Entry(raiz, textvariable=produccion)
prod.pack(side=tk.TOP)
contador = ttk.Button(raiz, text="sumador", command=sumar)
contador.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: wow amigo muchas gracias, me ayudaste con mi probloema y optimizaste mi codigo jejej, que no se note que apenas estoy aprendiendo jajaja.